# Visual and layout viewport and the document

Tags: html, css, browser, viewport

I've been reading the articles on quirksmode.org about viewports and the book "Web and mobile handbook" by Peter Koch, and I have some questions. This is the way i understand the world of viewports:

We have the visual and the layout viewport. They are equal to the width and height of the browser window. Actually the html element is constrained to the browser window. But what if we give width greater than the browser window? I now suspect that we have the document too that is different than the viewports. The document will have the now given width and the layout and visual viewports stay the same. And this is the same on mobile and desktop, except on mobile the visual and the layout viewports can be different.

I don't know if I understand this right. Can someone clarify this to me?

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html:

> The **visual viewport** is the part of the page that’s **currently shown on-screen**. The user may scroll to change the part of the page he sees, or zoom to change the size of the visual viewport.

If you are fully zoomed out, the whole page layout are shown on-screen. The visual viewport and the layout viewport are the same.

If you zoom in, some of the page layout will appear outside the screen. The layout viewport are larger than the visual viewport. The same thing happens if you have a layout width larger than the screen width, as in your example.

Look at this illustration from the article a cited above:

[image: Layout viewport]